# Replace image in active state exactly to cover static image Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to replace an image on active state to what is basically a button in jQuery Mobile, however, I have `data-role="none"` set in the `<a>` tag. The reason for this is that I don't want the styles applied to these "buttons" that jQuery Mobile normally applies.

I've got it sort of working, however, I can't get the image (the red one) to switch out exactly over the black one even though I have them set to the exact same size and placement in CSS.

What are the best practices for trying to accomplish this in jQuery Mobile?

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="content">
     <div class="maine">
        <a href="#" data-role="none"><img src="images/icons/Maine-Lighthouse@2x.png" style="text-align:left;margin-top:20px;margin-left:890px;" width="98px" height"85px"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   body .ui-content .maine a:active {

      background: url(images/icons/Maine-Lighthouse-Hover@2x.png) !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      text-align:left;
      margin-top:20px;
      margin-left:890px;
      width:98px;
      height:85px;
      z-index: 1000 !important;
   }
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/codewarrior_777/NppNA/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using pure CSS, I can think of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NppNA/31/)

**CSS**

```
.maine a img {
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
     text-align:center !important;
     background-size: 98px 85px;
     width:98px !important;
     height:85px !important;
     z-index: 10 !important;
 }

.maine a:active img {
     background-image: url(http://syntheticmedia.net/Maine-Lighthouse-Hover@2x.png) !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
     text-align:center !important;
     width:98px !important;
     height:85px !important;
     z-index: 10000 !important;
 }
```

Edit -

1. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/ehntb/3/) using img tag (there is a sort of border around image)
2. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/ehntb/6/) without using img tag

Comment: Thanks! That is close but the image http://syntheticmedia.net/Maine-Lighthouse-Hover@2x.png isn't replacing the black version. It should be a red color. jQuery Mobile CSS can be really tough sometimes.

Comment: Update the answer with 2 new fiddles.

Comment: That was it! The 2nd fiddle did it.